# ColdFusion 8 as WAR on JBoss 4.2.3 WEB-INF/flex-config.xml error

Tags: coldfusion, jboss, centos, war, coldfusion-8

I have done this by the book multiple times and have also tried using someone else's WAR to deploy, but I keep getting the same error. I am running JBoss 4.2.3 and have tried this on multiple installations (of 4.2.3)

I have verified that the supposed missing file file exists.

```
19:19:15,853 INFO [ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 54014 ms
19:19:18,172 ERROR [STDERR] javax.servlet.ServletException: The configuration file cound not be found at /WEB-INF/cfform/flex-config.xml
19:19:18,174 ERROR [STDERR] at flex.server.j2ee.cache.CacheFilter.setupFlexService(CacheFilter.java:93)
```

This error results in failure of the WAR to deploy:

```
--- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=cfusion.war,id=611163449
State: FAILED
Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/jee/workspace/tools/server/default/deploy/cfusion.war/ deployment failed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  It's insane, but it's worked twice now (on OS X, at least).

copy the WEB-INF directory to your file system root.

Ex:  cp -R ./cfusion.war/WEB-INF /

start the instance.  Everything works.

Delete the newly copied file system root /WEB-INF folder.

From now on, it will work.  Crazy, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this one a million times. It's usually when I forget a file in the WEB-INF of my war. Is flex-config.xml in your WEB-INF?

Comment: Yes, it is in my WEB-INF, I am using the built WAR from Adobe.